# Submit data from cells on google sheet A to Sheet B on button press

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I cant use forms to power the data collection into Google sheets due to limitations of forms and dynamic drop downs. However, I would like to create a collection set of boxes (like a form) in sheet A and have a submit button which pumps the data into a row on sheet B.

So for example:

Sheet A - in Cell A1 = Name : A3 = Group : A5 = System.

Each cell on sheet A which is listed above is a drop-down which is dynamically linked to each other. I then need to paste these entries into Sheet B into the next available row.

So sheet B would have A1 = Bob B1 = Team 2 C1 = New system and so on.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry the English

See if the following script can help you!

```
    function transferdata() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
  '***          ATTENTION          ***', 
  'Do you want to "SAVE" this information on the "Sheet B" tab',
  ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {

  var tab1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet A");

  var Name = tab1.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var Group = tab1.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var System = tab1.getRange("B5").getValue();


  var tab2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet B");
  var lr = tab2.getLastRow() + 1;

  tab2.getRange(lr, 1).setValue(Name);
  tab2.getRange(lr, 2).setValue(Group);
  tab2.getRange(lr, 3).setValue(System);


  tab1.getRange("B1").clearContent();
  tab1.getRange("B3").clearContent();
  tab1.getRange("B5").clearContent();


  ui.alert ('Information was successfully SAVED on the DATABASE tab');
   } else {
     ui.alert ('The information "NOT" has been saved!');

 }
}
```

Sidney

Comment: That's fantastic - worked 1st time. I am getting used to Google scripting but takes time. I would like to also insert a time/date stamp from when it is inserted is that possible? Also can you lift the user's name or email address as well and insert on the fly?